# What should the configure.win file contain in the cplex API package?

Tags: windows, cplex, rtools

I'm trying to install cplex API in windows. I'm not super familiar with the programme so I've been using this link from R bloggers

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/01/using-cplex-in-r-installing-cplexapi-in-windows-10/

After using the windows command prompt I get the following responses:

```
R CMD build --no-build-vignettes --no-manual  --md5     C:\Users\Rharris\Desktop\cplexAPI

* checking for file 'C:\Users\RHARRIS\Desktop\cplexAPI/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'cplexAPI':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
Warning in cleanup_pkg(pkgdir, Log) :
  unable to run 'make clean' in 'src'
* checking vignette meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* adding MD5 file
* building 'cplexAPI_1.4.0.tar.gz'
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
Warning: file 'cplexAPI/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected

C:\Users\RHARRIS>R CMD INSTALL --build --no-multiarch .\cplexAPI_1.4.0.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:/Users/RHARRIS/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
* installing *source* package 'cplexAPI' ...
** package 'cplexAPI' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'cplexAPI'
* removing 'C:/Users/RHARRIS/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cplexAPI'
```

It seems I have an error in the configure.win file, however I haven't edited it at all after downloading it. When I open it up its a blank file, I'm not sure if thats what I'm supposed to be.

If anyone has any insight to offer here it's be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this error message "'sh' not found" I suspect you should install cygwin so that the install can use the BourneShell.
If this fails, I guess you can contact the author of the package  https://www.th-koeln.de/personen/gabriel.gelius-dietrich/.
Cheers,

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I've since been shown that building the package within R has fixed the problem. For anyone else looking for a quick solution to the same problem, use the configure build tools from the build menu in Rstudio. Then you can select "package" from the drop down list and enter the arguments from the code that I linked in the original question. I assume the solution had something to do with the project or working directory that I had to set the command line to but I'm not very familiar with command line at all.